# Array of char pointers prints rubbish

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 3
void AddName(char *Names[],int *size)
{
    char str[100];
    int len;
    if (*size < MAX)
    {
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf(" %s", &str);
        len = strlen(str);
        Names[*size] = (char *)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
        Names[*size] = str;
        *size = *size+1;
    }else printf("Full Memory!!\n");
}
void PrintNames(char *Names[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf(" %s\t", Names[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


main()
{
    char *Names[MAX];
    int size = 0;
    int c;
    do
    {
        printf("=========================\n");
        printf("1- Add a new name.\n");
        printf("2- Print names.\n");
        printf("3- Exit.\n");
        printf("=========================\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%i", &c);
        printf("=========================\n");
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1: AddName(Names,&size);
            break;
            case 2: PrintNames(Names,size);
            break;
            case 3: printf("Good bye.\n");
            break;
            default: printf("ERROR: Bad input.\n");
        }
    }while(c != 3);
}
```

After i enter strings, when i print it using the function `printNames(Names,size)` it gives this output:

```
=========================
1- Add a new name.
2- Delete an old name.
3- Print names.
4- Exit.
=========================
Enter your choice: 1
=========================
Enter a string: John
=========================
1- Add a new name.
2- Delete an old name.
3- Print names.
4- Exit.
=========================
Enter your choice: 1
=========================
Enter a string: Carl
=========================
1- Add a new name.
2- Delete an old name.
3- Print names.
4- Exit.
=========================
Enter your choice: 3
=========================
  ):wç0@          ):wç0@
=========================
1- Add a new name.
2- Delete an old name.
3- Print names.
4- Exit.
=========================
Enter your choice:
```

What is the problem? I thought it might be missing '\0' but how can i added to each strings in the array `Names`?

Also if i try to free or delete one of the strings it turns to rubbish instead. This is the code:

`

```
void RemoveName(char *Names[],int *size)
{
    int loc;
    if (*size > 0)
    {
    printf("Starting from 0. Enter the name's location: ");
    scanf("%i", &loc);
    free(Names[loc]);
    }
```

`

Comment: Beware buffer overruns. For starters, replace `scanf(" %s", &str);` with `scanf(" %.*s", sizeof(str)-1, str);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't allocate memory for the null terminator:

```
len = strlen(str);
Names[*size] = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
                                   ^
```

And then you overwrite the pointer, instead of copying the string:

```
Names[*size] = str;  //pointer to allocated memory is lost
```

Should be something like:

```
strcpy( Names[*size] , str ) ;
```

There are other problems in the code, you can start with this.

Answer (score 2):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code. You first allocate memory to the pointer through `malloc` but then directly after *overwrite* that pointer and make it point to a local array, and as all other local variables it will go out of scope once the function returns, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Comment: One could mention that a string copy in C is done by strcpy() (I believe that was the intent of the OP's assigning `Names[*size] = str`).

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf(" %s", &str);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %s", str);
```

Do not need the cast for `malloc`

Probably think of a few other problems in a moment

**EDIT**

Missing adding space for the null character and using `strcpy`

**EDIT 2**

Also str is on the stack so it goes out of scope

Comment: Why the change in `scanf`?

Comment: Once upon a time I read the manual page http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf. Just needs a char pointer not a char pointer pointer

Comment: @EdHeal &str is the address of an array, not of a pointer. The array doesn't decay here. It also has the same numerical value, so while it may or may not be UB (I'm not sure) and should elicit a warning with better compilers it will almost certainly behave as expected.

Comment: I think you find that `str` is the pointer to the first character of that array

Comment: @PeterSchneider Ed is correct to point this out, &str is undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 - Thanks and an interesting number.

Comment: @2501 While the OP's scanf call with &str is UB and one should of course not write such nonsens, &str is emphatically *not* a "char pointer pointer", and will not decay to one. It is the address of the whole array (which starts, unsurprisingly, with its first element). Try adding one to it and print the numerical value.